# broken create, save, update, and destroy on Join record when using Postgres UUIDs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm creating uids using

```
create_table :users, { id: false } do |t|
    t.uuid :uid, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
    ... other columns
```

and setting `self.primary_key = :uid` in the models.

In general this works fine with ActiveRecord and I write `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations fine. However, when crossing a join table (i.e. `has_many ... through:`, I need to write custom SQL to get records.

I've figured out that I can in general do this by writing custom SQL, i.e. `SELECT * FROM main_table JOIN join_table ON main_table.uid = cast(join_table.uid AS uuid) WHERE condition=true)`

I've just recently realized that ActiveRecord's `create`, `destroy`, `save` and `update` dont work on the join model.

I have patched the four methods so they work, but it's too complex a sequence for my taste and probably unoptimal. Here are my patches:

```
def save(*args)
    # save sometimes works if it is called twice,
    # and sometimes works the first time but says theres an error
    super(*args) unless (super(*args) rescue true)
end
```

Sometimes, `save` issues a `ROLLBACK` the first time with no explanation. Then it works the second time. In other situations (I'm not sure why, possibly when updating), the first time it goes through successfully but if called a second time raises a TypeError. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568797/typeerror-nil-is-not-a-symbol/34115151) for another question about this error which doesn't have any answers for how to save a join when using uid instead of id. Here are my other (working) patches.

```
def create(*args)
    attrs = args[0]
    raise( ArgumentError, "invalid args to bucket list create" ) unless attrs.is_a?(Hash)
    bucket_list_photo = self.class.new(
        attrs
    )
    bucket_list_photo.save
    bucket_list_photo = BucketListPhoto.find_by(
        bucket_list_uid: bucket_list_photo.bucket_list_uid,
        photo_uid: bucket_list_photo.photo_uid
    )
    return bucket_list_photo
end

def update(*args)
    # similar bug to save
    attrs = args[0]
    raise( ArgumentError, "invalid args to bucket list update" ) unless attrs.is_a?(Hash)
    bucket_list_uid = self.bucket_list_uid
    photo_uid = self.photo_uid
    due_at = self.due_at
    self.destroy
    bucket_list_photo = self.class.new(
        {
            bucket_list_uid: bucket_list_uid,
            photo_uid: photo_uid,
            due_at: due_at
        }.merge(attrs)
    )
    bucket_list_photo.save
    bucket_list_photo = self.class.find_by(
        photo_uid: photo_uid,
        bucket_list_uid: bucket_list_uid
    )
    return bucket_list_photo # phew
end

def destroy
    # patching to fix an error on #destroy, #destroy_all etc.
    # the problem was apparently caused by custom primary keys (uids)
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26029997/2981429
    # however a custom fix is implemented here
    deleted_uids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
        "DELETE FROM bucket_list_photos WHERE uid='#{uid}' RETURNING uid"
    ).to_a.map { |record| record['uid'] }
    raise "BucketListPhoto not deleted" unless (
        (deleted_uids.length == 1) && (deleted_uids.first == uid)
    )
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.clear
    # since, the cache isnt updated when using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute,
    # reset the cache to ensure accurate values, i.e. counts and associations. 
end
```

I even ensured that `self.primary_key = :uid` in all my models.

I also tried replacing `uid` with `id` everywhere and verified that all the specs were passing (though I left in the patch). However, it still failed when I removed the patch (i.e. renaming the `uid` columns to `id` did not fix it).

**EDIT**

In response to some comments I've tried the `activeuuid` gem (where i got stuck on [an error](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid/issues/60)) and decided to totally switch over to ids. This is basically for simplicity's sake since I have pressure to launch this app ASAP.

Still, even with this fix I am required to patch `save`, `create`, and `update`. Actually the `delete` patch no longer works and I had to remove it (relying on the original). I would definitely like to avoid having to make these patches and I am keeping the bounty open for this reason.

Comment: Do gems such as https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid or https://github.com/madpilot/has_uuid address your issue?

Comment: Alternative approach: why not combine both `id` and `uuid` columns? The `id`, which is an incrementing number, is much more efficient to index and to ensure referential integrity. And use the uuid for outward facing presentation. And that way all the rails code will keep working :)

Comment: @twairball thanks for those recommendations. I tried activeuuid but wasn't able to fix this error. has_uuid looks cool but its readme says it's "not well tested enough to be released as a gem" so I'm going to skip it for this production app.  thanks for your advice nathanvda. I've ended up moving over to ids from uids completely for simplicity's sake. However I'm still having to use the same patches (except for destroy).

Comment: [friendly id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) would work with the auto incrementing Integer as key and still have a UUID or compound key for to_params method approach. Also FWIW you chose wisely reverting to Int ids. Its best not to fight Rails' conventions as that way lies madness

Comment: my personal experience i find that storing integer key while exposing a string UUID (for json api) is the way to go. Storing as `uuid` bit type has conversion costs for comparison too, not just hashing and indexing, but simple stuff like `User.find_by_uuid(user_params[:uuid])` is much easier in string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are pros and cons to retaining both `id` and `uuid`. For JSON APIs that expose `uuid`, using `Concerns` would be a Rails-ish implementation.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    include UserConcerns::Uuidable

end
```

app/models/concerns/user_concerns/uuidable.rb

```
module UserConcerns::Uuidable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        before_save :ensure_uuid!
    end


    def ensure_uuid!
        self.uuid = generate_uuid if uuid.blank?
    end

    def generate_uuid
        # your uuid using uuid_generate_v4() here
    end

    def to_param
        uuid
    end
end
```

Above implementation leaves out the uuid generation but I think above answer has a link to that.

Comment: this is a useful snippet. I'm still unsure of what is causing my broken CRUD (since I already switched to numeric ids), but perhaps it's a problem stemming from another context that i'm overlooking.

Answer (score 3):

I have provided 1 solution to generate UUID, I knew you switched back to id now.
[find link for UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196253/generating-a-short-uuid-string-using-uuidtools-in-rails/19516395#19516395)

Yes I agree we can not perform CRUD on joins table why don't you use active records relations to perform CRUD operations.

The important thing to understand is the convention by which Rails implements relationships using ActiveRecord. A book has many characters, and each character belongs to a book, so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecordBase
  has_many :characters
end

class Character < ActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Rails now assumes that the characters table will have a foreign key called book_id, which relates to the books table. To create a character belonging to a book:

```
@book = Book.new(:name=>"Book name")
@character = @book.characters.build(:name=>"Character name")
```

Now when @book is saved (assuming both @book and @character are valid), a row will be created in both the books and the characters tables, with the character row linked through book_id.

To show that a character also belongs to a user, you could add that relationship to the Character model:

```
class Character < ActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thus Rails now expects characters to also have foreign key called user_id, which points to a users table (which also needs a User model). To specify the user when creating the character:

```
@book = Book.new(:name=>"Book name")
@character = @book.characters.build(:name=>"Character name",:user=>current_user)
```

You can also assign the foreign key by calling the corresponding method on the object:

```
@character.user = current_user
```

This all works because it follows the Rails conventions for naming models and tables.

Comment: in what situations is it impossible to perform CRUD on join records? It works in other places in my app. I'm not sure what is different about this case.

Comment: Please find my updated answer, hope that will solve your problem. its all about rails convention.

Comment: I mean CRUD on associated models who follow referential integration in between.